# Javascript, convenience method for calling super class method from overwritten method

Tags: javascript

In order to emulate classical, Java-like classes in JavaScript I have a function called
"createClass":

It has 3 arguments:
* Name and path of the constructor function, that should be created.
* Path of the superclass.
* JavaScript object with methods of the class.

For example:

```
myApp.createClass("myapp.core.JString", "myapp.core.BaseString", {
  abc: function () {
  ...
```

First I create a constructor function

```
Cf = function () {
...
```

If there is a super class ("Base" is the constructor function of the super class):

```
protoObj = new Base();
protoObj.constructor = Cf;
```

Now, method by method of the new class, I put them on to the protoObj:
("protos" is the object with the "class" methods)

```
for (name in protos) {
  ????????????????????
  protoObj[name] = protos[name]
```

But before putting the methods to the protoObj, I want to create convenience methods for
calling superclass methods from overwritten methods:

```
init: function () {
  this.jstring_super_init();
...
```

So, where the question marks are, I want to place the following code:
(classnameLast in this case is "jstring" => last part of class path => lowercase)

```
if ((typeof protos[name] === "function") && 
    (protoObj[name]) && 
    (typeof protoObj[name] === "function")) {
  supername = classnameLast + "_super_" + name;
  protoObj[supername] = XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

In the place, where the multiple X are, I tried several things, but nothing worked. It should call the method of the overwritten superclass.

Many thanks in advance for your help

Comment: With what code is the super method supposed to be called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this for XXXXXXXXXXXX, and it worked:

```
(function(name1, Base1){
  return function() {
    Base1.prototype[name1].apply(this, arguments);                                                                       
  };
})(name, Base);
```

I debugged a "jstring_super_init" function call in Firefox 19, Firebug 1.11.2.

Firebug behaved very strangely, jumping to wrong places of the code!!

Then, I inserted "console.log(this.cid);" after the superinit-call.

The cid, which is placed on to "this" in the init method of the super class, was there!!

When debugging with Google Chrome Version 25, it jumps to the right function!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do something like this:

```
for (name in protos) {
    var super_function = ...; //wherever it comes from
    protoObj[name] = protos[name];
    protos[name]._super = super_function;
}
```

Then, from within the function, you should have access to the super function via `this._super`. You can even do `this._super.call(this, ...)` to ensure that the super function is called in the context of `this`.

Hopefully I'm understanding you correctly. Also, if I can make a suggestion, there might be an easier way to handle classical objects and inheritance. If you don't want to use Typescript, at least try the inheritance model that they use (which is quite common).

http://pastebin.com/Z2kaXqEv

EDIT: What helped me was using the Typescript playground (http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/). Play around with it and the class features it has, and see how it compiles to Javascript. That'll help you better understand exactly how you can accomplish classical inheritance in Javascript.